# Rhino Mocks: AssertNotCalled (except when I'm loading)

Tags: .net, vb.net, assert, rhino-mocks, arrange-act-assert

I have a dependency that gets called when the object I'm testing is created. However, it should never be called after that. How would I write such a test?

I'd like just this line as my test (since I'm trying to follow the AAA style of test writing). However, this assertion will fail since the `Publish` method was called during setup.

```
Notifier.AssertWasNotCalled(Sub(n) n.Publish(Arg(Of Message).Is.Anything))
```

Is there a way to "reset" the calls on the dependency I've mocked?

*Note:* I can set it up so that I check the property on the `Message` argument for a value I expect after initialization, but that makes my test more fragile/brittle and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

```
_notifier.AssertWasNotCalled(
  Sub(n) n.Publish(Arg(Of Message).Matches(Function(m) m.property = "yo!")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
_notifier.AssertWasCalled(function(n) p.Publish, function(c) c.Repeat.Once().IgnoreArguments());
```

As this would make sure it is called once only, which would be triggered by your setup code as you have indicated.

Comment: That works great! In my case, the method is called multiple times (I'm doing a `for each` over a list returned by a stubbed method)... but since I can just do `Repeat.Times(stubbedList.count)` is works fine (with no magic numbers). Yay!